# What is physically meant by "Partial derivatives are continuous "?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

What is the difference we see in the graph having partial derivatives continuous and a graph in which they are not continuous?
If I am having a function in more than one variable, then how to find whether it's partial derivatives at a point are continuous or not?For example ,in the function $$ f(x,y)=\frac{(x^2 y)}{x^2+y^2}$$, by looking at the graph [here](https://mathinsight.org/nondifferentiable_discontinuous_partial_derivatives) ,if we draw planes passing through origin then we can see the traces the graph makes on the plane and we can see that every trace is continuous and there is no drastic change in  slopes suddenly but it is given that the partial derivatives of the function are discontinuous at origin.How?

Also please explain with a couple of examples if possible?
And please suggest any book/books or any site where this is discussed

Comment: There is a 'pinch point' at the origin if you zoom in and the derivative does change suddenly at 0 along the direction of the 2 folds.